# Background color of navigation view not showing due to List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to set a background color for one of my views but when i implement a dynamic list in my ZStack, it completely covers the background color (red in this case). Removing the list shows the background color. Would there be a workaround for this? Thanks in advance.

 **The image below is what shows after running my code even with the red background.**

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            List{
                searchField

                if viewModel.dataSource.isEmpty {
                    emptySection
                } else {
                    cityHourlyWeatherSection
                    forecastSection
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("Weather ")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you can remove the default background on all lists and make it `clear`:

```
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Then change the colour of a `List`:

```
ZStack {
    Color.green
    List {}
}
```

Then change the colour of any individual item using this:

```
.listRowBackground(Color.green)
```